# Boosting in query upon source document properties

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

We are using [ES](http://www.elasticsearch.org) through the .Net  [Nest](https://github.com/Mpdreamz/NEST) client.

The Index document indexed looks like this :

```
   [ElasticType(
        Name = "tag",
        DateDetection = true,
        NumericDetection = true,
        SearchAnalyzer = "standard",
        IndexAnalyzer = "standard"
    )]
    public class TagIndexDto : AbstractIndexDto
    {

        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.analyzed, OmitNorms = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.analyzed, OmitNorms = true)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ElasticProperty(AddSortField = true)]
        public int FollowerCount { get; set; }
        [ElasticProperty(AddSortField = true)]
        public int ProductCount { get; set; }
        [ElasticProperty(AddSortField = true)]
        public int CatalogCount { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do is to give a specific boost upon the values of the 3 counts ( last 3 fields ). And the boost should be configurable , it means the exact value of the boost is not known at indexing time.
Is that actually supported by lucene ? ES ? Or I am looking for a nonexisting feature ?

Thanks
Roman

Comment: Why don't you boost those fields during querying?

Comment: Lucene supports boosting at different levels.. see http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/scoring.html#Score Boosting

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch it can be done using [Custom Filters Score Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html) (faster but less flexible) or [Custom Score Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query.html) (slower but more flexible)